# Search Widget fire ACTION_SEARCH intent twice when user search a word

Tags: android, search, android-intent

I follow the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) to write an application with search widget.

But I found that two `ACTION_SEARCH` intents are sent to the `SearchActivity`.  So, I doubt that is that my fault.
And then I try the **Google Play app**. I enter keyword to search app and I still capture two intents! Here is the logcat. So, how should be handle this? Even  I override onNewIntent with singleTop Activity, it need to search twice to handle one search operation!

> 04-18 22:26:19.007: I/ActivityManager(389): START u0
>   {act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity (has extras)} from pid
>   1721 04-18 22:26:19.007: I/ActivityManager(389): START u0
>   {act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity (has extras)} from pid
>   1721

Comment: Seems to be an API bug.  I plan on ditching the API search capability and just writing my own search event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the emulator when using the hardware keyboard.

http://books.google.com/books?id=OFXJXbCXjTgC&pg=PT771&lpg=PT771&dq=android+search+intent+sent+twice+bug&source=bl&ots=Ora1AJjh4A&sig=9yFBjCwJ1ARbXePHzcPYpG_QdFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bbddUpbZCcLi4AOiioCIAw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=android%20search%20intent%20sent%20twice%20bug&f=false

You can disable the hardware keyboard in the emulator by going to Settings -> Language & input and selecting Default.

When using the soft keyboard in the emulator I only get one intent.